# how to calculate and split a float value into two separate integer values ?? e.g 18.5f hours equals int h=18 int m=30

Tags: java, calendar

I am creating a Workday calendar program that calculates a 'start' and 'end' date

the results should output:

"Starting date: 24-05-2004 07:03 with addition of 8.276628 working days is end date: 04-06-2004 10:12"

or

24-05-2004 18:03 with the addition of -6.7470217 working days is 13-05-2004 10:02

The mathematical solution is to multiply hours pr day  with incrementInWokringdays
like 8.0f hours a day * 2.5f days = 18.4f hours and then the result of this should be added to the Date calendar this way

-date.add( Calendar.Hours_of_Day, 18.0f ) //but from float converted to integers 
-date.add( Calendar.Minutes_of_Day, 0.4f )//

how do i split the value 18.4f hours in to 
'int hours = 18;'
and 
'int minutes = 40;'
????

```
public Date getWorkdayIncrement(Calendar date, float incrementInWorkdays) {


    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
    System.out.println("start day: " + f.format(date.getTime()));

    // so if chosen incrementDays is 2.3 days and workinghours pr day is 7.5h you multiply them together to get total working hours
    float totalHoursWorkedPrDay = getWorkdayStartAndStop() * incrementInWorkdays;

    // needed to convert hours and minutes to integer values in order to increment calendar
    int hoursToIncrement = (int) totalHoursWorkedPrDay; //gets only hours

    // get the last to decimals 0.25 representing the minutes which means 25 percent of 60min
    float lastTwoDecimalsOfTotalWorkingHours = ((totalHoursWorkedPrDay - (float) hoursToIncrement) * 100);

    //calculate percent of minutes and convert to integer (25 / 100 * 60) = 15min
    int minutesToIncrement = (int) ((lastTwoDecimalsOfTotalWorkingHours / 100) *60);

    System.out.println("Hours to increment: " + hoursToIncrement);
    System.out.println("Minutes to increment: " + minutesToIncrement);

    //increment calendar
    date.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hoursToIncrement);
    date.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minutesToIncrement);

    Date endDate = date.getTime();
    System.out.println("End date excluding holidays: " + f.format(endDate));
```

}

Comment: Why should "7 hours and 30 minutes" be `1.50`? Did you mean `7.50`? Also, you explain **a lot** of unnecessary detail here, please try to focus on only the part that's relevant. And last but not least: how would you solve this on paper?

Comment: Why not study the classes in the java.time package and do this in a simpler and clearer way?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Its too late for me 2 re-do everything with  more modern classes. The given task to me was this way so i had no choice and i have to deliver the solution within a couple of days.

Comment: Well my comment was more off-topic and maybe I should have marked it so, you should focus on the first comment instead.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, `SimpleDateFormat` in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Even if you are receiving objects of the old-fashioned types, the conversions to modern types are straightforward, so still use java.time for your own work.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer
Well usually when i dont provide the rest of the methods people ask about them. 
And yes, that was mis-spelled by me sorry for that. 
I ment if 1.0f workingday = 7.0f hours and 0.30f minutes which date is the end date with the addition of e.g 6.5 working days?  I have updated my solution so hopefully its more clearly now. 
So on paper this would be 7.5h *  x.x days (incrementInWorkdays)
and result of that addet to startdates.add(Calendar.Hour_of_day,   result);

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t follow everything you were doing in the question. So for now I focus on calculating the working hours of a working day given start and end time. I am assuming that you get start and end as `GregorianCalendar` objects from some legacy API that you cannot afford to upgrade to java.time just now.

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Even if you are getting your data as objects of the old-fashioned date-time types. java.time is so much nicer to work with.

```
static float getHoursBetween(Calendar start, Calendar end) {
    ZonedDateTime startZdt = ((GregorianCalendar) start).toZonedDateTime();
    ZonedDateTime endZdt = ((GregorianCalendar) end).toZonedDateTime();
    long wholeDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startZdt, endZdt);
    startZdt = startZdt.plusDays(wholeDays);
    Duration workDay = Duration.between(startZdt, endZdt);
    return (float) workDay.toMinutes() / (float) Duration.ofHours(1).toMinutes();
}
```

The method ignores the date difference between start and end by adding the number of full days to the start time. This means that the result we get is based only on the hours and minutes. To try the method out, let’s construct a couple of `GregorianCalendar` objects (of course I am using java.time for that too):

```
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Araguaina");

    ZonedDateTime workDayStart = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 6, 14, 7, 30, 0, 0, zone);
    Calendar workDayStartCal = GregorianCalendar.from(workDayStart);
    ZonedDateTime workDayEnd = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 6, 15, 15, 15, 0, 0, zone);
    Calendar workDayEndCal = GregorianCalendar.from(workDayEnd);

    float workingDay = getHoursBetween(workDayStartCal, workDayEndCal);

    System.out.println(workingDay);
```

Output from the example is:

> 7.75

Edit: for the opposite conversion this works since Java 9:

```
    float hours = 7.75f;

    Duration dur = Duration.ofMinutes(Math.round(hours * Duration.ofHours(1).toMinutes()));

    System.out.println("Hours:   " + dur.toHours());
    System.out.println("Minutes: " + dur.toMinutesPart());
```

> ```
> Hours:   7
> Minutes: 45
> ```

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: No,I allready have the working hours between 2 dates, but your version is much cleaner. this represents how many hours you register to work pr day e.g 8-16 = 8.0hours a day  

The 4th method is the troubled one. It receives a Start Date, and a float value representing number of days to work. The return value should return Which date you get when you finish working. Solution is to multiply HOURS and MINUTES pr day with number of days to work. 
And then add those hours and minute values to the new date. How to split that result value in float to 2 integer values H and M????

Comment: It can’t be too hard except taking holidays into account, I have not understood how that is supposed to work. I may revert tomorrow.

Comment: how to split e.g 74.5 (74h and 50m)  into two different integer variables. i need them seperately to add to the given calendar.

Comment: You don’t want 74.5 to mean 74 hours 50 minutes. You want it to mean 74 and a half hours, in other words, 74 hours 30 minutes. Or maybe you should not want to use `float` for a number of hours at all but prefer `Duration`.

Comment: yes this is the confusing part to me.
1. I need the calendar to switch day whenever e.g 8h workingday as passed 
2. and then check if that day is a holiday, then skip to next day.and so on

Comment: The reason i am using float is because i have to multiply it with how many days to work which is in float too.


public Date getWorkdayIncrement(Calendar date, float numberOfDaysToWork) {  }

Comment: Please see my edit for how to convert for example a `float` of 7.75 to 7 hours 45 minutes.

Comment: Duration.toMinutesPART()  does not appear. I just upgraded to jdk 14 but it still does not show. Im using Intellij

Comment: tried this too:  dur.minusHours(dur.toHours()).toMinutes()) but still gives me 0 value when inputing 1.5 days

Comment: probably because it only calculates on the left side of the decimals (hours)

Comment: Weird. I have run my code on my Java 11, and the quoted results are from there.

Comment: the maven compiler  config.source is set 1.8. does that say anything to you?

Comment: when running java -version it still says ''java version "1.8.0_251"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_251-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.251-b08, mixed mode)
''   is this correct??

Comment: Well, it means that you are running on a Java 8 virtual machine. Which is one explanation why you can’t call `Duration.toMinutesPart()`. Also having config.source set to 1.8 will probably prevent you from it.

Comment: I don’t know your setup. I can’t tell. And in any case it’s outside the scope of this question, sorry.